# Preview throwing error in SwiftUI: ConfigurationError: noPreviewInfos

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using Xcode 12.4 in macOS Catalina 10.15.7 version. While preview SwiftUI code:

```
import SwiftUI
struct SwiftUINewView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Ayush Gupta")
    }
}

struct SwiftUINewView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUINewView()
    }
}
```

I am getting error:

`ConfigurationError: noPreviewInfos(arch: "x86_64", sdkRoot: "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk")`

Is there any solution for this issue? Actually I am trying to integrate SwiftUI in old/existing UIKit project which is now supporting iOS 13.0 SDK.

Comment: I'm getting this on Big Sur 11.3 on M1 (`ConfigurationError: noPreviewInfos(arch: "arm64", sdkRoot: ...`) also, with Xcode 12.5 (12E262).

Answer (score 64):

I have a solution that is perfectly working fine for me.

Go to **Editor** -> **Canvas** -> Disable/Uncheck "**Automatically Refresh Canvas**"

[image]

Comment: This solution also works in Xcode 13.0 (13A233) and macOS 11.6.

Comment: I am curious to learn why this works

Comment: Worked for me, thanks for posting!

Comment: After that my app crashed :) when preview on :)

Comment: Makes sense. Disabling "Automatically Refresh Canvas" fixes my Canvas so it refreshes automatically :-|