# Cannot preview in this file - unexpected error occurred Swift ui error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm getting this error. Unable to resolve it. does anyone have idea how to fix this
i checked this [StackOverFlowQuestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70481424/swiftui-cannot-preview-this-file-unexpected-error-occurred) but it have no right answer

HumanReadableSwiftError

ProviderError: ProviderError: noPreviewInfos(runDestination: Simulator - iOS 15.5 | iphonesimulator | arm64 | iPhone 13 | Apple Watch Series 7 - 45mm, thunkConfiguration: <IDEBuildOperationConfiguration buildCommand: 8, buildParameters: IDEBuildParameters:0x142674760:action=build:command=<IDEConcretePrimitiveSchemeCommand:0x167775cb0:Run:config=Debug:dest=iPhone 13:arch=arm64:workspaceArena=<IDEWorkspaceArenaSnapshot: 0x1426a88f0>:
overridingProperties=(
{ // Preview overrides (immutable)
DSTROOT = 【:/Users/aqibjaved/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testapp-cturdetitylfkjgmrwlzbfpgfnnl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/testapp Debug/ReleaseProducts】
ENABLE_PREVIEWS = 【YES】
OBJROOT = 【:/Users/aqibjaved/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testapp-cturdetitylfkjgmrwlzbfpgfnnl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/testapp Debug/Intermediates.noindex】
SYMROOT = 【:/Users/aqibjaved/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testapp-cturdetitylfkjgmrwlzbfpgfnnl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/testapp Debug/Products】
},
):
collectBuildTimeStatistics=NO
collectTimelineMetrics=NO>, executionEnvironment: Optional(<IDEExecutionEnvironment: 0x16aaf7500>), singleFileToBuild: nil, buildLog: nil, parallelizeBuildables: true, dontActuallyRunCommands: false, buildImplicitDependencies: true, skipDependencies: false, buildables: Optional([<Xcode3TargetProduct:0x168029ee0:testapp.app blueprint:Xcode3Target:0x16779b410:testapp>]), subsetOfBuildables: nil, buildDescriptionID: nil, scheme: Optional(<IDEScheme:0x13269c750:'testapp Debug'>), schemeTask: 0, clientInfo: nil>, blueprintName: testapp, sourceFilePath: Source/Listing/Views/Headers/ListingTopHeaderSwiftUI.swift, thunkVariantSuffix: **XCPREVIEW_THUNKSUFFIX**)

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/661263)?

Comment: cannot apply this . although i read about this